# Azure DevOps Trigger build on release/{version} branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-flow

For Azure DevOps, how can you automatically build when you create a release branch in the formation release/{version}?

Looking at the triggers tab of a build, the filter allows me to select a branch, but that is only for pre-defined branches, and not a branch type / format.

I don't know yet what the branch name will be as it will follow a version string format like release/{major}.{minor}.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just type in whatever you like, so in your case use:

```
release/*
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#release-triggers

Comment: Agreed.  And if that doesn't work, try playing around with the path to the branch reference with "refs/heads/feature/*" or something similar.  But 4c74356b41's answer should initially work.  Hint:  If you want your build to execute when tagged do "refs/tags/*".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting a branch, you can also enter a variable that contains the branch name.

For example, if variable `$(currentReleaseBranch)` contains the value `releases/M23` then you can enter this variable in the branch field.

A release will be triggered if the build is from `releases/M23`. Variables from variable groups can be used across multiple release pipelines